# Click event doesn't fire in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I appended a new element but when I click on it it has no response.

HTML

```
<button>add element</button>
<div></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').append('<span class="x">x</span>');
    });

    $('.x').click(function(){
        alert('fire'); 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('div').append('<span class="x">x</span>');
  });

  $('div').on('click', '.x', function() {
    alert('fire');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>add element</button>
<div></div>
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating elements.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Example

```
$('div').on('click', '.x', function(){
    alert('fire'); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

One cannot bind click events to dynamically generated elements through calling `$(".x")` when the element does not exist in the document. 
One of the solution is to use Event Delegation, which is something like

```
$(document).on("click",".x",function(){
// do your work here
})
```

And the other way to do that is do bind the click event to the element when it is generated

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').append($("<span>",{
          class: x
    }).text("x").click(function(){
          // do your work here
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the event listener before the item with the x class exists. You want to add that event listener right after you append that span.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').append('<span class="x">x</span>');
        $('.x').click(function(){
            alert('fire'); 
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind events directly to dynamically created elements in jQuery.

Use event-delegation to bind to the dynamically created element's parent:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').append('<span class="x">x</span>');
    });

    $('button').on("click", ".x", (function(){
        alert('fire'); 
        });
});
```

For more information on this, see: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I had another issue why the event was not fired.

In my case  it was beause of CSS `pointer-events` was set to `none`

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events